# How to send parameter class and create new object from it in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics

Is that posible to send parameter class and create new object from it in method ?

So i want to create a method will return List of object in Generic.

This is and example, i have 2 class Genre and Actors and this 2 classes have a sampe properties Name.

**Genre Class**

```
public class Genre
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

**Actor Class**

```
 public class Actor
 {
     public string Name {get;set;}
 }
```

**Program Class**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string test = "Adam,John,dan";
        string test2 = "Comedy,Action";
        List<Genre> a=  ConvertStringToList<Genre>(test2);
        List<Actor> b=  ConvertStringToList<Actor>(test);
    }

    public static List<T> ConvertStringToList<T>(string genreList) where T :new()
    {
        List<T> genres = new List<T>();
        foreach(var str in genreList.Split(','))
        {
            string Name = str.Trim();
            genres.Add(new T(){Name});

        }
        return genres;
    }
}
```

in code below i cant create new object using `new T()` and fill the properties.

any idea for solve this problem ?

Comment: I've added an answer, but maybe it could be solved easier. Why not returning `List<Genre>`? Or should the name of the method something like ConvertStringToListWithNames?

Comment: ohh i forgot to change naming method lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create an interface and use that as constraint

Create an interface and implement:

```
public interface IName
{
    string Name {get;set;}
}


public class Genre: IName
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Actor: IName
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And use:

```
where T : IName, new()
```

Now you could do:

```
var t = new T();
t.Name = name;
```

### Func

Another option is to send a Func,

Change signature to:

```
ConvertStringToList<T>(string genreList, Func<string, T> createFunc)
```

Instead of `new T()`, use `createFunc(name)`:

```
string name = str.Trim();
genres.Add(createFunc(name));
```

Usage:

```
ConvertStringToList<Genre>(test2, name => new Genre{Name = name});
```

PS. No need for the `new()` constraint when using this method

Comment: but i dont want to use interface, any idea ?

Comment: Added another option :)